# Why do silent changes made by “Community ♦” show up in the front page?

Tags: support, community-user

I have often seen, on the front page, a question from years ago showing up as “Active” due to an update made by “Community ♦”. Specifically, [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/94156/iphone-3gs-turning-off-randomly-while-being-used/?lastactivity) does not show any activity with `?lastactivity` (accessible from the front page by clicking the link that looks like “24m ago”).

The revision histories of [the question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/75005/revisions) and [both](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/75006/revisions) [answers](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/83937/revisions) show nothing indicating an edit.

I don't know why it shows up in the “Active” section if the changes made are silent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Questions with no or no upvoted answers (as the one referenced in the question) will get reinfected into the front page a few times automatically to get more attention. As no user is involved the user is shown as "community".

Like many users, community has a profile page that explains what they like to do on the site. In this case, community is a robot that randomly pokes these questions:

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community

Comment: @grgarside Whether it shows "Community" or the actual user of the deleted post depends on your reputation. If you are allowed to see deleted posts (>10k) you see the user. Otherwise you see "Community".

Comment: Was this a recent change? On other sites where I have <10k I think I still see the user for deleted content — feel free to rollback though :)

Comment: Even if you can't see the deleted answer? Hmm, you're probably right then :-)

Comment: I am far below 10K and see the actual user when answers are deleted. It is occasionally confusing (more so when I first started noticing it)